# Sorting an array with instances of a custom class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array filled with instances of a custom class which contains two String properties, firstname and lastname. Both have a getter method which is equal to the name of the property itself. There is also a method for retrieving the Full name of a person called "getFullName". Consider the example below.

```
 CustomClass *person = [[CustomClass alloc] ...];
 person.firstname  // Returns "Thomas"
 person.lastname // Returns "Meier"
 [person getFullName] // Returns "Thomas Meier"
```

Now I would like to sort this Array by Fullname in a descending Order. I have been looking at some array sorting methods but was not quite able to figure out how to go about this. I guess that I have to create some kind of comparison function which compares two elements, yet how do I tell the SDK which values to pass to this method and where should I place it (in the custom class or in the class where the sorting happens?). Maybe there is another/better way of going about this? Admittedly I have close to none experience with sorting arrays.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Ps. The code should run on iOS 3.2

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. One is to put a comparison method on the custom class. Call it `-compare:` or something like that. That method should take another object of the same custom type as its input. It should return `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending`, or `NSOrderedSame`, depending on the result of the comparison. (Inside this compare function is where you look at your own fullName versus the passed-in object's fullName.)

Then you can use `NSMutableArray`'s [`-sortUsingSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingSelector:) method, like this:

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

This works on all versions of iOS. There are block comparison methods available in 4.0+.

Comment: Don't ask me why, but I just realized how this system works when I read your post:) Awesome, now the stuff makes sense. Thanks a lot! I think the link posted as comment to my question is a shortcut to creating a separate custom method, yet your post certainly works too.